# SQL State to Find Record that meets certain date criterion

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I am use ADO SQL in VBA to try and need the solution to the following example:

Table

```
ID   Effective Date of Documentation
1    1/1/2015
2    6/1/2015
3    1/1/2016
4    6/1/2016
```

In the example above the documentation for the ID 1 is in effective from 1/1/2015 through 5/31/2015, for ID 2 its in effect from 6/1/2015 through 12/31/2015, and so forth. So if I have a date say 8/1/2015, then I need to return the record which the documentation is in effect for. So in this example the record for ID 2 would be returned. I need some SQL to accomplish this and I cant figure out how! Any ideas? Is this possible to do with this structure or do I need to create some artificial column first for the end date and query that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing:

```
select t.*
from table t
where effdate < @date
order by effdate desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is the SQL standard syntax.  Different databases might have different syntax for selecting one row.

EDIT:

In MS Access you would do:

```
select TOP 1 t.*
from t
where effdate < @date
order by effdate desc;
```

Comment: The fetch first 1 row only seems to draw an error in ado sql. Any other ways to do this last line that might work with ado sql which seems to use more basic sql commands.

Comment: @IrishRedneck . . . Use whatever equivalent method is appropriate for your database.

Comment: Yea im a bit of a noob with figuring out what works for ado sql but il figure it out. thanks for the overall solution tho!

Comment: @IrishRedneck . . . It is not ADO.  It is the underlying database.  Either `SELECT TOP 1` or `LIMIT 1` should work.

Comment: TOP 1 AND LIMIT seem to draw an error. I am using an access database.

Comment: Nevermind I was doing Select Top 1 * From (the query you originally made minus the fetch) . Just adding in Top 1 works to your query works

Comment: Actually I would think the sign should change to less than but for some reason its returning no values. In theory I  would want to take all values less than the @date then order by descending.